# Can I use MSE as loss function and label encoding in classification problem?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, mnist

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import models, layers
from keras.utils import to_categorical

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
 
network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28 * 28,))) 
network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')) 

network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                loss='mean_squared_error',
                metrics=['accuracy'])


train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28 * 28)) 
train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255

test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28 * 28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255        

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

network.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=128)

test_loss, test_acc = network.evaluate(test_images, test_labels, batch_size=128)

print("test_acc: ", test_acc)
```

```
Epoch 1/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 41us/step - loss: 0.2600 - acc: 0.9244
Epoch 2/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 34us/step - loss: 0.1055 - acc: 0.9679
Epoch 3/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 33us/step - loss: 0.0688 - acc: 0.9791
Epoch 4/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 35us/step - loss: 0.0504 - acc: 0.9848
Epoch 5/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 38us/step - loss: 0.0373 - acc: 0.9889
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 18us/step
test_acc:  0.9791
```

It seems that there is no problem in training process, but I'm not sure how MSE is calculated. In this case, does keras(or tensorflow) automatically convert label encoding to one-hot encoding when calculating MSE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have manually converted your labels to one-hot encoding already via :

`train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)`

As your softmax layer contains 10 nodes I will assume you intended for classification of 10 labels, meaning `train_labels` will look something like:

```
[
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],...  <--- One of these per training row
]
```

See the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical) on this.

The softmax output for that row may look like :

```
[0.033,0.45,0.01,0.9,0,0,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.95]
```

As explained in this handy [resource](https://machinelearningmastery.com/softmax-activation-function-with-python/#:%7E:text=The%20softmax%20function%20will%20output,%5B0%2C%201%2C%200%5D):

> The softmax function will output a probability of class membership for
> each class label and attempt to best approximate the expected target
> for a given input.
>
> For example, if the integer encoded class 1 was expected for one
> example, the target vector would be:
>
> [0, 1, 0] The softmax output might look as follows, which puts the
> most weight on class 1 and less weight on the other classes.
>
> [0.09003057 0.66524096 0.24472847]

And then the mean squared error is calculated on those two sets of data, with the true labels `y_true` as per the `to_categorical` output and the predicted labels `y_pred` being the softmax output from your network.

From the tensorflow source code on [MSE](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L1165-L1198), this works by:

1. First calculating the difference between `y_true` and `y_pred` and squaring the result i.e. with the above two:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops

y_true = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
y_pred = [0.033,0.45,0.01,0.9,0,0,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.95]

math_ops.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true)


<tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([1.0890000e-03, 2.0249999e-01, 9.9999997e-05, 1.0000004e-02,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 2.5000000e-01, 1.6000001e-01,
       9.0000004e-02, 9.0249997e-01], dtype=float32)>
```

2. And then the mean of the result:

```
K.mean(math_ops.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.1616189>
```

This is obviously just for single example but it handles multi-dimensional calculations in the same way as per the below simplified example:

```
>>> y_true = [[1,0],[0,1]]
>>> y_pred = [[0.95,0.03],[0.3,0.8]]
>>> K.mean(math_ops.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true))

<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.03335>
```

You can see that the result is a single number every time, and that's your loss.